# Purge every package with a given string in its name

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, aptitude

What I want do is to purge (via aptitude purge) every package installed with a given string in its name.

E.g. apache2. I've got several packages with the string apache2 in their name installed on a system. Now I want to aptitude purge *apache2* (like apache2, apache2.2-bin, libapache2-mod-ruby, etc.). But I do not find a way to do this.

Thanks for your answers in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick troll through the Aptitude Reference Manual on patterns I found [this entry](http://algebraicthunk.net/~dburrows/projects/aptitude/doc/en/ch02s03s05.html#searchTermName).

Working from that, `aptitude purge ?name('apache2')` will do what you want, but if you're wise you'll run it with `-s` the first time so you can see what all it'll remove before committing to the task.

Comment: Meanwhile I had the opportunity to try this. Unfortunately, it doesn't work :(. -bash: Syntaxfehler beim unerwarteten Wort `(' (Syntax error on unexpected word `(')

Comment: You may need to escape the ()s from your shell.

Comment: This works brilliantly and as mentioned by @Shadur it has to be escaped as ```sudo aptitude purge ?name\('apache2'\)```

Answer (score 2):

I would parse the output of dpkg --get-selections, doing something along the following.

```
$ dpkg --get-selections | cut -f 1 | grep apache | sudo xargs aptitude purge -y
```

(For better understanding, feel free to try the pipe out one step at a time.)

Comment: That was what I feared first, that I had to use the xargs command. But I hoped that there would be a built-in solution as Shadur pointed out. Thanks for your answer.