# apt-get does not remove initscript?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, apt, init.d, remove

This day I tried to remove **apache2**. It's bundled with Ubuntu Lucid, which I don't need. I used `apt-get remove apache2` to remove it. But somehow, the initscript was still there, in "/etc/init.d/". I tried the `apt-get purge` command, but the result was the same.

How come the `apt-get` command fails not remove initscript, even though the script was made by **apache2** package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exact owner of the init script is `apache2.2-common`, not the `apache2`. The `apt-get purge apache2` command will purge the `apache2` package but only remove `apache2.2-common` as its dependency. You should name all packages you want to purge to actually purge them or use the reciept from https://serverfault.com/a/326306/52873.

Answer (score 3):

The init script is not removed because it is considered to be a configuration file, or "conffile" (because some people might want to tweak their init scripts).  In Debian (and derived distributions) conffiles are kept on the system when packages are uninstalled, to make it easier if you want to re-install them later.

If you're sure that you want to remove the conffiles as well, then you should pass the `--purge` option to `apt-get` or `aptitude`.

Comment: Yeah I tried the `--purge` option as well as `apt-get purge apache2`. But it still did not work out well. I read the man, it said `remove --purge is equivalent to the purge command`. So the two commands I used is exactly the same. It's funny to know that this kind of thing do not happen in debian.

Comment: @jollyroger I believe this is the best answer. Many thanks!

Comment: Moved my comment as a separate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `apt-get remove apache2 --purge` ?

Answer (score 1):

A more low-level method to remove the package is:

```
dpkg --purge apache2.2-common
```

(I checked the right packages name for you is: apache2.2-common)

Comment: Yeah this one worked! Only I had to remove apache2-mpm-work first. Because there's dependency problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

> dpkg --purge --force-depends apache2.2-common

then:

> apt-get install apache2.2-common

The `--force-depends` makes sure it just removes that package only. It will break your dependencies, but since you're immediately reinstalling it afterwards, it shouldn't be an issue.